# запись в csv в цикле

Tags: python, csv

Тут я записываю данные в csv файл, в функцию передаю 2 параметра которые в дальнейшем записываются:

```
def sav(name, co):
   with open('employee_file2.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
      fieldnames = ['emp_name', 'dept', 'birth_month']
      writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

      writer.writeheader()
      writer.writerow({'emp_name': name, 'dept': co, 'birth_month': 'November'})
```

функция `nnn` принимает в себя 3 параметра обрабатывает их и передает в функцию `sav(name.rstrip(), co)`

Тут же у меня принт `print(name.rstrip() + " " +co)`:

```
def nnn(name, url, co):
   u = "@"+url[-2] +"."+url[-1]

   name0 = name.split(" ")
   if len(name0) == 1:
      ....

   elif len(name0) == 2 or len(name0) == 3:
      try:
        .....
         sav(name.rstrip(), co)
         print(name.rstrip() + " " +co)

      except:
         pass
```

Функция `nnn` вызывается в цикле много раз и print выводит очень много значений, но когда я открываю сохраненный файл csv там всего 1 строка. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените `mode` на `'a'` (добавление новых строк к уже существующим в файле):

```
with open('employee_file2.csv', mode='a') as csvfile:
    #...
```